# How to implement an inventory system?

Tags: html, web-applications

I am trying to implement an inventory system for a small clothing business. Basically I would like a website (disregarding user credentials) where the owner can log how many hoodies he's delivering, he currently has "in progress", etc etc. There are a couple parameters such as color, size, etc.

What do I use to make this kind of web app?
     - HTML for visuals
     - PHP for visual aspects
     - and mySQL for database?

Comment: Hire a company to implement it ;-).

Comment: If your requirements are as vague as that, work in whatever technologie you are most familiar with. HTML/CSS/PHP/MySQL/Javascript/AJAX are sufficient for what you need.

Comment: Ok well more specifically, how would I handle storing the data in a database? Would MySQL be the simplest/best option?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your very vague description, I would suggest that any one of a number of freely available open source content management systems could be configured to satisfy your requirements without too much difficulty.

E.g.

- http://drupal.org
- http://joomla.org
- http://wordpress.org